# What is the value range for absolute value formulation of binary variable

Tags: binary

According to this link [binary variables - absolute values](https://www.fico.com/fico-xpress-optimization/docs/latest/mipform/dhtml/chap2s1.html?scroll=ssecabsval) the formula of some binary variables like absolute value is :

y = | x1 - x2| for two variables x1, x2 with 0 ≤ xi ≤ U

Introduce binary variables d1, d2 to mean

d1 : 1 if x1 - x2 is the positive value
d2 : 1 if x2 - x1 is the positive value

MIP formulation

0 ≤ xi ≤ U  [1.i]

**0 ≤ y - (x1-x2) ≤ 2 · U · d2  [2]**

**0 ≤ y - (x2-x1) ≤ 2 · U · d1  [3]**

d1 + d2 = 1 [4]

Notice the bolded numbers, what do these 2s represent? Do they represent the value range? Aren't the value range is only from 0 to 1?

Sorry, I'm totally new to this.

Answer (score 0):

That's just basic inequalities, there is no trick.

- if $d_1 = 1$, then $d_2 = 0$, and $y = x_1 - x_2$. That means that:
  $$y - (x_1 - x_2) = 0 \leqslant 2 \times U \times d_2 = 0$$
- if $d_1 = 0$, then $d_2 = 0$, and $y = x_2 - x_1$. That means that:
  $$y - (x_1 - x_2) = 2x_2 - 2x_1 \leqslant 2\times U - 2\times 0 = 2\times U \times d_2$$

Same thing for the other inequality.

Comment: According to the link, it said "Binary decision variables take value 0 or 1". The values can only be from 0 to 1. What do these 2s represent? I'm sorry, I have a very limited background in maths

Comment: $d_1$ and $d_2$ take values in $\{0,1\}$. Those are the binary decision variables.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So, those 2s in y−(x1−x2)=0⩽2×U×d2=0 and y−(x1−x2)=2x2−2x1⩽2×U−2×0=2×U×d2 represent 1?

Comment: What are you saying? Those 2's are representing 2, not 1… This is $2 = 1 + 1$, because there is two occurrences of $x_1$ and $x_2$. Honestly, I don't even understand what is the problem. $x + x = 2x$, and this $2$ is not $1$.

Comment: Oh sorry for that, so the value range is still 0 to 1? Not 0 to 2? My problem is that because it is binary variables which strictly involved only 0 and 1, so my initial thought is that there cannot be number 2 in there. But only 0 and 1

Comment: What are you talking about?? In the inequality $y - (x_1 -x_2) \leqslant 2 \times U \times d_2$, the value $2\times U \times d_2$ is not the value of $d_2$, why should it only be $0$ or $1$??

Comment: Ok, I'm really sorry about this. Why is the number 2 chosen there? Is it part of the formula?

Comment: I give up. You should try to understand middle school math before doing computer science.

Comment: Oh, I think I finally get it. The 2s in these formulations

0 ≤ y - (x1-x2) ≤ 2 · U · d2 [2]

0 ≤ y - (x2-x1) ≤ 2 · U · d1 [3]

refer to x1 and x2?